# NullPointException on OnClickListener Button

Tags: java, android, button, nullpointerexception, listener

I'm making a simple app and want a user to click start to move to the next activity but when implementing the start button I keep getting a NullPointerException when it is pressed at runtime. I'm confused because it seems like the FindViewByID is returning null on the ID of the button (startbutton) even though it is included in the XML file. Been stuck on this for hours and have searched for other solutions and tried cleaning and rebuilding. Using Android Studio 2.2.3 if that helps. Thanks.

XML file **activity_start_screen.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="top|center"
android:weightSum="1">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="Quiz App"
    android:textSize="36dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="0.34" />

<Button
    android:text="Start!"
    android:layout_width="245dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/startbutton" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Main Activity Code **StartScreen.java**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.app.Activity;

public class StartScreen extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private Button startbutton;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start_screen);
    //set start button
    startbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startbutton);
    startbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            //go to quiz screen
            //change activity
            Intent QuizScreen = new Intent(StartScreen.this, QuizScreen.class);
            startActivity(QuizScreen);

        }
    });
}
}
```

**Stack Trace**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.paavan.quizappcoursework, PID: 2305
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.paavan.quizappcoursework/com.paavan.quizappcoursework.QuizScreen}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                  at com.paavan.quizappcoursework.QuizScreen.onCreate(QuizScreen.java:63)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) 
Application terminated.
```

**QuizScreen.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class QuizScreen extends AppCompatActivity
{
private Button mTrueButton;
private Button mFalseButton;
private Button mNextButton;
private TextView mQuestionTextView;

private Question[] mQuestionBank = new Question[] {
        new Question(R.string.question_oceans, true),
        new Question(R.string.question_mideast, false),
        new Question(R.string.question_africa, false),
        new Question(R.string.question_americas, true),
        new Question(R.string.question_asia, true),
        new Question(R.string.question_uk,false),
        new Question(R.string.question_europe,true),
        new Question(R.string.question_waterfall,false),
        new Question(R.string.question_giraffes,false),
        new Question(R.string.question_penguins,true),
};

private int mCurrentIndex = 0;

private void updateQuestion()
{
    int question = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].getTextResId();
    mQuestionTextView.setText(question);
}

private void checkAnswer(boolean userPressedTrue)
{
    boolean answerIsTrue = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].isAnswerTrue();

    int messageResId = 0;

    if (userPressedTrue == answerIsTrue) {
        messageResId = R.string.correct_toast;
    } else {
        messageResId = R.string.incorrect_toast;
    }

    Toast.makeText(this, messageResId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    mQuestionTextView = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.question_text_view);


    mTrueButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.true_button);
    mTrueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            checkAnswer(true);
        }
    });
    mFalseButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.false_button);
    mFalseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            checkAnswer(false);
        }
    });

    mNextButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.next_button);
    mNextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex + 1) % mQuestionBank.length;
            updateQuestion();
        }
    });

    updateQuestion();

}



}
```

**quizscreen.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" >



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/question_text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="24dp"
    />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/true_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/true_button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/false_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/false_button" />

</LinearLayout>


<Button
    android:id="@+id/next_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/next_button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post your log  please,, and are your sure your button is in activity_start_screen.xml?

Comment: Is the XML file included activity_start_screen.xml?

Comment: Which line causes the error?

Comment: Added the trace and yes that is activity_start_screen.xml. Caused by the setOnClickListener call.

Comment: The problem is in `onCreate()` in QuizScreen.java

Comment: There is no problem in the code in the question.  Show your QuizScreen.java code...

Comment: Added it. Didn't think the error would be in this part because its from a textbook.

Comment: Have you added code to QuizScreen.java after that stack trace was taken?  Line 65 doesn't make sense....

Comment: Also, just to be sure, you have quizscreen.xml in the res folder?  Show that as well....

Comment: Sorry yeah reverted it, Line 63 on this and yep quizscreen.xml is in res\layout.

Comment: What happened to your `setContentView()` call?  Looks like it's not there now....

Comment: Added it back in along with super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); and it worked. Would that have been the issue? Thank you for your help anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to add the layout to activity.**

Before doing any initialization of widgets in **onCreate()** add the layout using
setContentView(R.layout.your_layoutfile);

```
public class QuizScreen extends AppCompatActivity
   {
        @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.quizscreenlayout);

    //initialize your widgets
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_start_screen, null);

Button startbutton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.startbutton);
```

Comment: What? This makes no sense.  Why would the code in the question not work as-is?

Comment: Thanks this seems to have gotten rid of the error! Do you mind explaining it because this has confused me.

Comment: This answer does not make any sense, What u trying to do here?

Answer (score -1):

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener) 
   on a null object reference at 
   com.paavan.quizappcoursework.QuizScreen.onCreate(QuizScreen.java:65)
```

This null pointer exception is in 65th line in Quizscreen.java. Please check whether all button id's are there in quizscreen.xml.

Comment: checked quizscreen.xml and seems like they are all there. will post code in main question.

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.quizscreen) is missing